# Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135) after trying to open program that use GLEW sources

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glew

My program uses glew sources, to build project I use CMAKE. After my program compiled, its it starts and closes immediately and at the same time in console I see this:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Also my program uses GLFW

My CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project("Aura Engine")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

add_subdirectory( Aura/Engine/Dependencies/GLEW/build/cmake )
add_subdirectory(Aura/Engine/Dependencies/GLFW)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories(GLFW/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Aura/Engine/Dependencies/GLEW/include)

add_executable(Main main.cpp Aura/Engine/Dependencies/Libs.h Aura/Engine/Core/Window.cpp Aura/Engine/Core/Window.h Aura/Engine/Core/Input.cpp Aura/Engine/Core/Input.h)
target_include_directories(Main PRIVATE Aura/Engine/Dependencies/GLEW/include)
target_link_libraries(Main glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
target_link_libraries(Main GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(Main glew32s glfw3 opengl32)
```

Comment: 0xC0000135 means DLL not found. A library is not installed correctly or the program is looking for it in the wrong spot.

Comment: But how I can include GLEW to project?(Maybe I neew to show my CMakeLists.txt?)

Comment: Sounds like you want to statically link GLEW. I have to walk away at this point because I don't know how to do that. Popping `site:stackoverflow.com statically link glew` into google (or a similar instruction into the search engine of your choice) may find something useful while you wait for someone who does know how to do this correctly.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?

Comment: I use CMake 3.6

Comment: The CMake version 3.6 doesn't have the ability to distinguish between the shared and static libraries via use of the `find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)` Find Module. So, you may have to manually link the static library: `target_link_libraries(Main PRIVATE /path/to/your/glew/libGLEW.a)`. Otherwise, you should upgrade to the latest CMake and simply use `target_link_libraries(Main PRIVATE GLEW::glew_s)`.